# Writing a video in openCV 2.4.3 with lower fps than its source

Tags: c++, opencv, video, computer-vision

I'm trying to write a .avi video using OpenCV 2.4.3.
What I am going to do is:

- load a .avi video
- do some stuff over each frame, eventually discarding some of them
- save the new video

Basically, what I do is:

- use a face detector and find faces
- if no faces are detected, skip that frame
- if there are faces, draw a rectangle on each one and put some text over it

The code looks like this (skipping the main elaboration part, which doesn't touch the `Mat alt` frame):

```
VideoCapture cam("1.avi");
VideoWriter writer("1_det.avi", 
           cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),
           cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
           cv::Size(cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
           cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));

while(cam.read(image2.img)) {
    Mat alt = image2.img.clone();
    // finds faces, then:
    if(faces.size()==0) {
        for(int k=0;k<5;k++) cam.read(alt);
        continue;       
    }
    for(int f=0;f<faces.size();++f) {
        // do some stuff here, then draw some results:
        putText(alt, ss.str(), Point(faces[f].x,faces[f].y), FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, 1, Scalar::all(255), 1);

        rectangle(alt, Point(faces[f].x,faces[f].y), Point(faces[f].x+faces[f].width,faces[f].y+faces[f].height), colors[f] , 3, 8, 0 );
    }

    writer << alt;

}
```

Now, since I discard a significant number of frames, I would like to save the video at a lower FPS, like `cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)/2` but if I try to do something like that, the video shows the first frame repeated over and over again, for the entire duration of the video (which is correct though).

Is there something big I'm missing about videos..?

Any input will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me how you tried to do that.  Did you try to first assign an int variable to cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) and then divide that variable by 2?

Comment: Yes, i tried. No significant differences between dividing `cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` in the `VideoWriter` constructor or assigning `cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` to a variable, dividing the variable and then using it in the constructor.